# Julia: Prevent printing of dataframe after function execution

Tags: dataframe, julia

I was trying to change some of my dataframe fields to type categorical as follows:

```
categorical!(df, [:Column1, :Column2])
```

Upon completion of the function execution, which took much longer than expected, the dataframe was printed (partially) in my console. **My questions** are

1. is it possible to prevent printing of dataframe upon function execution
2. why is the execution taking long? (i suspect it is due to the printing of the dataframe)

I'm using Julia 1.0.3 in an interactive session with Jupyter Lab 0.35.3. Package versions during function execution are:

```
CSV v0.4.3
CategoricalArrays v0.5.2
DataFrames v0.15.2
Distributions v0.16.4
IJulia v1.14.1
```

Comment: If you put a semicolon at the end of the statement, is printing suppressed?

Comment: oh gosh it is. thanks for this. new to julia here. :)

Comment: to add, the prolonged execution time does appear to be caused by the printing. after adding the semi-colon as suggested by @rickhg12hs, the execution was instantaneous.

Comment: The long printing times in Jupyter Notebook are fixed on current version 0.16 of DataFrames.jl. The lag was caused by the fact that Jupyter Notebook cached LaTeX representation of the whole data frame, which is slow for large data frames.